# Asking to skip the check in meetings and 1 on 1s and quarterly goal setting? How to make my boss care less about me?

Tags: management

I joined a new company a few months ago. My new company has apparently embraced bureaucratic management. So every two weeks we spend an hour talking about nothing in particular. They are supposed to be employee driven, but there is very little I am willing to say so it ends up being question and answer with me just repeating that "I am happy" and "I need nothing."

Bluntly, I would never involve my boss in professional development as my professional growth strategy is geared towards departure. He talks about getting a promotion in two years and I plan to get that some promotion at another company in a shorter timeframe.

I also would never bring up any issues I have. I either overcome them myself, sidestep them, or just accelerate my departure timeline. You don't say bad things to management as people shoot messengers.

I am concerned that he is wasting his time in an employee he is not going to retain and that increased investment can be frustrating when the employee eventually leaves, increasing the sense of betrayal from employee departure.

Is there a reasonable way to get out of these meetings? Some excuse that is plausible to the purveyors of useless management theory? I want to keep the boss happy now as well as when I leave (for a reference down the road).

Comment: He probably feels the same way about the meetings

Comment: @Kilisi so I can just ask to be set free?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the company is fine. The rest of the 2 week I get to write code except for standup. Pay is good. Reputation is good. I don't fit the culture, but with remote work can hide from it anyway. In the grand scheme of things this is not a big deal. I just find social games exhausting personally.

Comment: @PlayerOne it's a really opinionated question - it's almost a leading question, really. Also, the premise *is* deeply flawed.

Answer (score 17):

> Bluntly, I would never involve my boss in professional development as my professional growth strategy is geared towards departure.

Then to put it bluntly you're a fool - and wasting your greatest asset in driving your professional growth. The fact that you don't plan on being there for the promotion is irrelevent, by growing to the point where you're ready for that promotion you're proving to yourself and your next employer that you are indeed ready. Leaving the "..and I plan to do that elsewhere" bit unsaid is normal and reasonable. With a bonus that engaging with your current employer in growth gives you a great plan B should the market not have any opportunities you want when you look.

> I also would never bring up any issues I have. I either overcome them myself, sidestep them, or just accelerate my departure timeline. You don't say bad things to management as people shoot messengers.

If you're having (and solving) issues then you're again missing a trick - no one's going to believe you never have any issues. Instead bring up that you had issue x and solved or overcame it by doing y, you look like a self-sufficient rock star.

> I am concerned that he is wasting his time in an employee he is not going to retain and that increased investment can be frustrating when the employee eventually leaves, increasing the sense of betrayal from employee departure.

So you'd rather he thought of you as sullen and uncommunicative? I'd rather have someone be annoyed enough at losing me to feel betrayed than have them thanking whatever deity they prey to that I'd gone!

> Is there a reasonable way to get out of these meetings? Some excuse that is plausible to the purveyors of useless management theory? I want to keep the boss happy now as well as when I leave (for a reference down the road).

If you're determined to get out of these **and** keep your boss happy then the best way is to drive them in the direction of proving you're doing great and are self-sufficient. Not whining like a toddler who's been asked to put their coat on to go outside, i.e. not an excuse but actual performance and evidence of that. Which brings us back to my earlier suggestion, engage with the process *demonstrate* your self-sufficiency by recounting any issues/challenges you've had an resolved, or are outstanding and the plan you have to overcome them. Drive the meetings this way and you can control the agenda (no more talking about "nothing in particular") so that it's done and dusted in shorter time periods, and eventually you might reduce their frequency or eliminate them altogether.

Even if you have to keep having them you'll reduce the time impact. Plus your boss will think you're awesome.

Answer (score 6):

Oh lord.

Ok, so look, this is going to be fun to say: this is why technology people don't get ahead. Even if they're gifted. Then they look at "bad technologists" who earn multiples of their salary and who "aren't as smart as them" but got promoted ahead of them, and then come to sites like this and complain about bad management.

It's a slow day - I have to check in with one of my companies in a few hours, so let me just utterly burn you.

> My new company has apparently embraced bureaucratic management

No they have not. They are actively managing their staff, this is how a company should be run. If your manager doesn't talk to their staff every week (or two, I prefer weekly), then are they actually managing? Or are they just an easily replaceable time tracker?

Your manager *should* be talking to you this often, and they *should* have tried to break through your icy demeanour to work out what it is you want.

> but there is very little I am willing to say so it ends up being question and answer with me just repeating that "I am happy" and "I need nothing."

I ask you this - what do you *actually* want? What is it? A tool? Training? More money? How are you proposing to get it if nobody knows you want it? What steps are you taking, aside from, apparently, very quiet ones?

Look at your leaders - political, business - are they quiet? Is Elon Musk "quiet"? Do you ever have any doubt what Donald Trump might want at any particular moment? You don't get the things you want by silently waiting for them to arrive.

You have things you want, you have an hour every two weeks to ask for them. I would suggest you ask for them in that hour.

> He talks about getting a promotion in two years and I plan to get that some promotion at another company in a shorter timeframe

Oh fascinating, so you want a promotion in a shorter time frame. Have you thought of maybe asking your boss, at each and every meeting, what steps you need to take to get that promotion? Or if you could take on the responsibilities that someone with that promotion has?

I *strongly* suggest you ask this question. If you must hold onto your tired viewpoint that management is evil or inept or whatever, then consider this: You will be hearing, directly from managers, how you should position yourself to this magical next company you're going to move to. You will know the key words to put on your cv, you will be able to describe in the terms managers use the ownership you took on. *Even if you never took on that ownership*.

> I either overcome them myself, sidestep them, or just accelerate my departure timeline.

You've been at this place "a few months" and you're already accelerating your departure timeline? Why are you even here? What is honestly going on? But as a thought, why not use this time with your manager to *show* all the amazing things you've overcome or side-stepped? Why not detail how great you're doing?

And why not ask for help on the issues that are so bad they're accelerating your timeline?

> You don't say bad things to management as people shoot messengers.

Possibly. I'm not really sure of this though - how many actual *messengers* have gotten shot? I cannot think of any. Perhaps speaking out of turn - or rudely - might get you in hot water. But that is generally not applicable when you're asked for your opinion.

> I am concerned that he is wasting his time in an employee he is not going to retain and that increased investment can be frustrating when the employee eventually leaves, increasing the sense of betrayal from employee departure.

Well, yes. But also it is annoying when you're trying to *stop* the employee from leaving and you're asking things like "what do you want" and "how can we make you happy" and the employee doesn't say anything and then leaves. That's more annoying, and the kind of thing that you recall when you're later on asked for a reference.

Of course, generally, that's not how *references* work anymore. But let me tell you a little something about *networks*. See, at some stage you stop *applying* for jobs and get them directly delivered to you. People come up to *you* and say "we want you on our team". But they cannot say that if they don't know you - typically it is people you've met before, like managers or co-workers who enjoyed working with you, found your communication style open and your work output brilliant.

And this is why you nowadays want to leave with everyone thinking well of you - because you don't know who is going to think, in the future "gosh, we want to work with someone, who was someone who really shone?"

> Is there a reasonable way to get out of these meetings?

Yes. Say you don't want them anymore, and you want to leave the company for unspecified reasons to get a promotion. That will surely end those meetings quickly.

> Some excuse that is plausible to the purveyors of useless management theory?

No, sadly they want those meetings to find out what makes you tick, to inspire you to work harder and to keep you happy. That is the literal purpose of them. As you go up the ladder - a ladder you seemingly want to climb, the way you talk about promotions - they become *more* important.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reasonable way to get out of these meetings? Some excuse
> that is plausible to the purveyors of useless management theory? I
> want to keep the boss happy now as well as when I leave (for a
> reference down the road).

Sit through the meeting, smile, nod and mentally solve a crosswords puzzle.

As your goal is to leave on the best terms possible, not to stay and fix the company, a bit of boredom every 2 weeks seems like a low price to pay for that.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Incorrect answer. Even if your boss is a bone head there is always something you can learn in a meeting like this. OP can ask about corporate things and processes, etc. What's blocking here is the attitude of the OP.

Comment: @Hilmar but op doesn't want to learn about the company, he wants to run the clock without rocking the boat. I agree that his attitude is wrong, but then I don't live OP's life to make those decisions for him.

Answer (score 3):

You're only a few months into a new company - I would wait it out a bit.

Sure it wastes an hour of both your time, but it's probably something HR is insisting on with all new employees and it's likely that it will get less frequent as time goes on.

You say:

> I would never involve my boss in professional development

I understand that you plan to get the promotion else where a lot quicker, BUT the point is you're still looking to get it, so you still want to have professional development, letting him help you could mean more responsibility and skilling up faster and more efficiently (both will be great things to talk about in the interviews to come!)

**My advise is not to try and "get out" of these meeting, but rather just find ways to get-more-out of them.**

Try and *show* your boss you're doing well, not just say it. That will mean he can mark a bureaucratic check box allowing him to make the meetings less regular.